# Does ClipX work on Windows 7 / 2008 R2 x64 SP1?

Tags: windows, clipboard

ClipX always crashes these days.  It seems to still work on my laptop, which I have not yet updated to Windows 7 SP1, but it crashes on my desktop PC and servers.

I have started using Ditto, but after using ClipX for years, I am not taking to it.  I don't like the way it does not automatically go to the previous clipboard entry and I cannot find any way to have 'sticky' clips.

So, can ClipX work on Win7 / 2008 R2 SP1, or is this the end for ClipX, seeing as it has not been updated for a long time?  Or is it possible that I am now running something in my standard environment that is incompatible with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a few months of using Ditto, and finally getting fed up with it, I tried using ClipX again, and found that it does indeed work perfectly well on Windows 7 SP1 and 2008 R2 SP1.

I still have no idea why it was crashing before (on different OS installations).

Answer (score 1):

The way that applications interact with the clipboard seems to have changed at a fundamental level with Win7/2k8R2. We have a few applications that rely on clipboard operation that need to be rewritten because of this.

I think it's safe to assume that ClipX will probably not be usable unless it's updated.

Comment: But I have been using it with Windows 7/2008 R2 until recently.  I think that SP1 has changed things for ClipX, but I am not completely sure.  I use a lot of virtualization and RDP, which could be confusing things.

Comment: Whaaat????  Please elaborate on this fundamental change.  I'm the author of a clipboard extender, and I haven't been aware of any fundamental changes since the Vista-style clipboard notification.

Comment: I don't know exactly what the change was. I'm not a developer, but all of the custom .NET applications that our developers created had to be rewritten for Win7 because the clipboard integration just stopped working. Perhaps it was a certain library that they were using.